# Insertions data into multiple tables using triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have 4 tables i.e, A,B,C,D and A is parent table and b & C are child tables.For a tuning query,I am creating another table 
i.e., D.In this table some fields of B & C.If any CRUD operations occurs in those two table I want insert/update into d table.So I trying to
append D table insertation in  those table triggers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER A_ADUIT_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETING on per
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD

IF (INSERTING) THEN

INSERT INTO D(ID) VALUES(:OLD.ID);
ELSIF (DELETING) THEN
INSERT INTO A_AUDIT(ID,ID_NAME,TEST) VALUES(OLD.ID,OLD.ID_NAME,OLD.TEST);
END IF;
```

Its compiled and remaining tables trigger not included "D" TABLE inseration. When i am trying test at my application side and the logic
insert/update in table "A","B","C" and got expection that is B.ID Cannot insert null.But i have ID Value.I am suspected the issue at
insert of D table.If i remove insertation on table d in trigger and its working fine.Is it possible multiple table handled in triggers
Please help on this.

Comment: Why are you inserting the `:old.id` rather than the `:new.id`?  On an `INSERT`, the `:old` values are all NULL and the `:new` values are whatever you're actually inserting.  In the same way that when you `DELETE`, the `:new` values are all `NULL` and the `:old` values are the state of the row before it was deleted.

Comment: You also need `FOR EACH ROW` if you're going to refer to `NEW` and `OLD`